# Why does the property google:mimetype not working with web content when indexed with the Google Search Appliance?

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am attempting to display the mimetype of documents indexed by the Google Search Appliance and am using the property `google:mimetype` as documented at https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/connectors/200/connector_dev/cdg_traversing. The context I am however using it is to show the mimetype for documents/files that are served by a web server e.g. a PDF file that is served from a web server and it doesn't seem to work i.e. it does not display the mimetype when look at the metadata attributes.

Can the property `google:mimetye` be used with content from web servers not is it limited to file shares, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are feeding content that is then fetched from a web server.  The GSA ignores your suggestion for mimetype.